# How avoid changing numpy array's shape when appending?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

i am trying to read 30 images and create a large numpy array from it by appending the numpy array for each image to that one single array so that i can use it later in a flow function for keras.

I have an empty list to which I am appending numpy arrays after doing face detection in a loop, after which I am creating a large numpy array from this list. The problem is that when,I create a numpy array from this list, it changes the shape of my array, which was originally (1,139,139,3), to (30,1,139,139,3). It basically adds the total number of images at the start as I am appending, and I want to get back to original shape. I do not want to use reshape as that might affect the data.

Here is the code:

```
img_width, img_height = 139, 139
confidence = 0.8
#graph = K.get_session().graph
data1 = []
def get_face(path):
    with graph.as_default():
        img = io.imread(path)
        dets = detector(img, 1)
        output = None
        for i, d in enumerate(dets):
            img = img[d.top():d.bottom(), d.left():d.right()]
            img = resize(img, (img_width, img_height))
            output = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
            break
        return output

for row in df.itertuples():
    data1.append(get_face(row[1]))
data1 = np.array(data1)
print(data1)
```

Comment: You're (most probably) creating a list of 30 numpy arrays of shape (1,139,139,3), which gets converted to (30,1,139,139,3), just as it should be. I think you need to add more context on what you want to achieve. Also, don't be afraid to use reshape, it doesn't randomly affect data. As long as you understand what it's doing nothing bad will happen.

Comment: @Fulaphex i added some more context as i want to have a numpy  with the shape of (139,139,3) having stored all the images which then i want to use later. i tried reshape but it did not work

Comment: A single image has 139x139x3 integers, when you want to store data from 30 images you'll have 30x139x139x3 integers. You cannot really overcome this unless you reduce your matrix over the first axis. (30, 139, 139, 3) array would be an array of 30 pictures you loaded.

Comment: @Fulaphex oh ok.. but i guess an array of (30,139,139,3) will solve my issue as my main problem was that i was getting an error of **array can have rank 4** while my array has status (30,1,139,139,3). if i can somehow remove 1 that might solve the issue.

Comment: you sure you need that `expand_dims` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @filippo pointed out you probably want to omit `np.expand_dims`.

```
img_width, img_height = 139, 139
confidence = 0.8
#graph = K.get_session().graph
data1 = []
def get_face(path):
    with graph.as_default():
        img = io.imread(path)
        dets = detector(img, 1)
        output = None
        for i, d in enumerate(dets):
            img = img[d.top():d.bottom(), d.left():d.right()]
            output = resize(img, (img_width, img_height))
            break
        return output

for row in df.itertuples():
    data1.append(get_face(row[1]))
data1 = np.array(data1)
print(data1)
```

This piece of code will produce a list of 30 numpy arrays with shapes `(139, 139, 3)`. Calling `np.array` constructor on that will give you array with shape `(30, 139, 139, 3)`. You should also read documentation for [np.stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) and [np.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html). Using the second function you can actually get what you want keeping `np.expand_dims` if for whatever reason you might need this.

Comment: Keras 2D layers work with 4D tensors with shape `(samples, rows, cols, channels)`, if you're using `channels_last` ordering. When you're working with single image batches it is common to call `expand_dims` so you still have a 4D array. Guess that call is probably left there from some tutorial that expected a single sample.

Answer (score 1):

`np.array` joins the elements of the list on a new front dimension:

```
In [141]: alist = []
In [142]: for i in range(2):
     ...:     arr = np.zeros((3,4))
     ...:     alist.append(arr)
     ...:     
In [143]: np.array(alist).shape
Out[143]: (2, 3, 4)
```

`expand_dims` adds a new dimension:

```
In [144]: alist = []
In [145]: for i in range(2):
     ...:     arr = np.zeros((3,4))
     ...:     arr = np.expand_dims(arr,0)
     ...:     alist.append(arr)
     ...:     
In [146]: np.array(alist).shape
Out[146]: (2, 1, 3, 4)
```

`concatenate` joins on an existing dimension:

```
In [149]: np.concatenate(alist, axis=0).shape
Out[149]: (2, 3, 4)
```

An alternative to `np.array` is `np.stack`.